# Using a Proxy to check mailbox exists in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtplib, socks

I'm trying to build a simple email verifier using Python.

I am having trouble testing `@me.com`, `@icloud.com` among others.

I am trying to implement a proxy to get around this as I think my IP from my ISP is blocked by the receiving mailbox. I am trying to use Socks 5 and PySocks.

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong? Thanks!

```
import smtplib
import socks
import socket

socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "*****", ***)
socks.wrapmodule(smtplib)

print('Enter email:')
address_to_test = "***@me.com"

smtp = smtplib.SMTP('gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com')
host_exists = True
smtp.helo() # send the HELO command
smtp.mail('*****@gmail.com') # send the MAIL command
resp = smtp.rcpt(address_to_test)
if resp[0] == 250: # check the status code
    deliverable = True
    print("250")
elif resp[0] == 550:
    deliverable = False
    print("550")
else:
    print(resp[0])
```